# State store throws exception when run from docker-compose

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dapr

I have a simple Dapr project for state management. I have one model class holding data and storing that model data into a redis state store. I have a `statestore.yml` file for configuration.

When I run project with `dapr run --app-id [appname] --app-port [port] dontnet run` command in the command line while running default images (redis, zipkin, daprio/dapr) freshly pulling from dockerhub, the state store endpoints work.

However, when I create a docker-compose and run it, then I end up with exception shown below. I couldn't find the exact solution for this on Stack Overflow. Does anyone know what could cause this issue?

======  docker-compose.yml =======

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  daprtestapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}daprtestapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DaprTestApi/Dockerfile
    ports:
     - "52000:50001"
    depends_on:
     - redis

  daprtestapi-dapr:
    image: "daprio/daprd:latest"
    command: ["./daprd", "-app-id", "daprtestapi", "-app-port", "80", "-components-path", "/DaprTestApi/Components"]
    depends_on:
        - daprtestapi
    network_mode: "service:daprtestapi"

  redis:
    container_name: "dapr_redis" 
    image: "redis:latest"
```

======== Exception Thrown ==============

```txt
Dapr.DaprException: State operation failed: the Dapr endpoint indicated a failure. See InnerException for details.
 ---> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="FailedPrecondition", Detail="state store is not configured")
   at Dapr.Client.DaprClientGrpc.GetStateAndETagAsync[TValue](String storeName, String key, Nullable`1 consistencyMode, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 metadata, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Dapr.Client.DaprClientGrpc.GetStateAndETagAsync[TValue](String storeName, String key, Nullable`1 consistencyMode, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 metadata, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Dapr.Client.DaprClient.GetStateEntryAsync[TValue](String storeName, String key, Nullable`1 consistencyMode, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 metadata, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Dapr.AspNetCore.StateEntryModelBinder.GetStateEntryAsync[T](DaprClient daprClient, String storeName, String key)
   at Dapr.AspNetCore.StateEntryModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value, Object container)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
:authority: localhost:57104
:method: GET
:path: /get/1
:scheme: https
Accept: text/plain
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: language=en,region=en-US
Host: localhost:57104
Referer: https://localhost:57104/swagger/index.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36 Edg/93.0.961.38
sec-ch-ua: "Microsoft Edge";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
```

Comment: What the `DaprTestApi` look like and how are you trying to access the state store?

Comment: @tmarwen DaprTestApi is very simple .net core API with controller to expose endpoints. I'm calling dapr client method to add data in statestore. I have statestore configuration yml as well. This is code for adding data to statestore which throws exception. `var state = await daprClient.GetStateEntryAsync<ProducerStore>(StoreName, pDashboard.Id.ToString());
            state.Value ??= new ProducerStore() { Id = pDashboard.Id.ToString()};
            state.Value.Dashboard = pDashboard;

            await state.SaveAsync();

            return Ok(state.Value); `

Answer (score 1):

There should be a statestore.yaml as the configuration file. And in the docker-compose.yaml, a "volumes" section is used for mapping the path of statestore.yaml on your host to /DaprTestApi/Components, such as:

```
daprtestapi-dapr:
    image: "daprio/daprd:latest"
    command: ["./daprd", "-app-id", "daprtestapi", "-app-port", "80", "-components-path", "/DaprTestApi/Components"]
    depends_on:
        - daprtestapi
    network_mode: "service:daprtestapi"
    volumes:
        - [path for statestore.yaml]:/DaprTestApi/Components
```

Finally ,the statestore.yaml seems like:

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: statestore
spec:
  type: state.redis
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: redisHost
    value: redis:6379
  - name: redisPassword
    value: ""
```